# How to compare two dataframe columns without using for loop?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am used to C++ style coding and having problems understanding how to convert a code comparing two dataframe column valued and create a new dataframe based on that without using for loops. My sample code is given below.

```
for(i in seq(1,nrow(DF1))){

    for(j in seq(1,nrow(DF2))){
      if(DF1$some_col1[i]==DF2$some_col1[j] && DF2$some_col2[i]!=all_df$some_col2[j]){
        DF3[nrow(DF3)+1,]<- c(DF1$some_col1[i],DF1$some_col2[i],DF2$some_colm[j])

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example using dput() of both the dataframes

Comment: It would be a good idea to check how to write a good question in the help centre

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I will assume what you meant is you want to compare a column ( lets call it `col1`) from dataframe (lets call it `df`) to another column from the same dataframe ( lets call it `col2`).

I think you are trying several conditions on several columns from the same dataframe, and then if all conditions are met, you want to insert the values from those rows into a new data frame.

```
df = dataframe(col1 = c(1,2,3,8), 
               col2 = c(1,3,0,8),
               col3 = c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE))
```

Now we do what i think you wanted:

```
newDF = df[ df$col1 == df$col2 & df$col3) , ]
```

now `newDF` will be a subset of your dataframe :

```
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    1 TRUE

4    8    8 TRUE
```

modifying it will make not alter the original `df`.

**Some clarification:
In R you rarely need to use index variables if you are not using a loop. The reason is that R vectors support vector operations so instead of having a for loop with an index go through the entire column to check a condition, you can just specify the condition/operator and the vectors, R will do the rest:

```
>VEC1 = c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
>VEC2 = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)

>VEC1 & VEC2
[1] TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: I am trying to compare columns of two different dataframes with different length. I updated my example if that helps